# Does COD BO 4 Battle Edition include all gameplay content for Battle Royale, unlocked?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

Call of Duty Black Ops 4 [has just added](https://investor.activision.com/news-releases/news-release-details/call-duty-black-ops-4-battle-edition-available-now-pc) a new lower-priced "Battle Edition" for sale, which includes only the multiplayer game modes. This appeals to me because I wanted to try the Battle Royale mode, but didn't have much interest in the rest of the games and don't want to spend any more money.

If I purchase the Battle Edition, will that mean I will be able to permanently play Battle Royale fully-unlocked without gameplay limitations? (I don't mind being cut-off from cosmetics.) To be a bit more specific:

- There is "Black Ops Pass" for sale which unlocks additional multiplayer maps. Are these maps relevant to Battle Royale, or only the traditional multiplayer mode?
- There are unlockable characters for Battle Royale. Are these cosmetic, or do they effect gameplay?
- There is some kind of "points" currency that you can earn through gameplay. Are these only for cosmetics in Battle Royale?
- Is there any other kind of gameplay content that needs to be unlocked, either through play or pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's cosmetic, and the maps in the DLC aren't blackout related. Blackout only has 1 map currently.

None of the gameplay in Blackout is gated behind a transaction of any kind. The points system is similar to Fortnite's battle pass and only allows you to unlock cosmetics.

If you end up picking up the game, enjoy!